# Grails Test Suite - Specify test order

Tags: grails, testing, functional-testing, spock, geb

I am trying to get my geb-spock functional tests to run in a specified order because SpecA will create data required for SpecB during its run.

This question is about running the specifications in order, not the individual test methods within the specification.

I have tried changing the specification name to indicate execution order but that didn't work. I found a solution where a Test Suite was used, and the tests were added to the suite in order, but I can't find how to make a test suite work in Grails.

Explicitly specifying them as `grails test-app functional: SpecA SpecB` , is not a long term option, as more specs will be added.

Comment: if you want, that you initialize some data in first test, then use this data in second, so it's very very bad idea. For example: you have situation when you have an error under test SpecB, so that all be good you should run 2 tests only with one thing that in prevision initialized data. So good solution create in src class or interface, the last better, for initialize data. for example: createuser(String email);

Comment: I am currently working on making tests independent, but I want to know if its possible to specify execution order.

Comment: I think they sort by name.

Answer (score 0):

For sequential or whatever the sequence you want to run your tasks, I do the following thing in my build.gradle file:

```
def modules = ["X", "Y", "Z", "ZZ"]

if (modules.size() > 1) {
    for(j in 1 .. modules.size()-1 ) {
        tasks[modules[j]].mustRunAfter  modules[values[j-1]]        
     }
}
```

Hope that helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your question but a general advice - don't do this. Introducing data setup dependencies between test classes will make your suite brittle in the long run. Reasoning about what the state is at a given point will get harder and harder as the amount of tests grows and the global state size with it. Later on hanging a test or introducing a new one might break many tests downstream. This is just asking for trouble.

Ideally, you want to setup the data needed by a test immediately before that test and tear it down afterwards. Grails [Remote Control plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/remote-control) and test data fixture builders are your friends here.

Comment: I have now changed it so that SpecB will setup everything before it runs, trying to figure how to reset DB when it starts.. Regardless I am still interested in any approaches for achieving the question aim..

Answer (score 0):

You should define your initialization code in a single place, and if it's shared between both Specs, it may be a good idea to create a superclass with methods you can call in each Spec's set up methods, or a whole class devoted to declare testing methods to reuse.

In any case, the purpose of a unit test is only to test a single functionality, and it shouldn't be responsible of setting up other tests as well.